# Why display the user's points who answered the question?

Tags: discussion

There are a few users who have reputation points in the 10,000+ range.  I feel for the most part, they are derserving of those points.

However, I feel often users will tend to accept/vote up their answers because of the status rather than the content.

I have seen several cases where the answer was given by someone in this elite group and their answer accepted, even though I don't think it was the best answer.  I fear that this is demotivating other's to answer.

If feels that many if not most answers are awarded to people in this group.  I question if it is solely because of the content or their perceived intelligence.

My question is this: Why display the points of the user?  Shouldn't the content be what we judge and not the author?

Comment: ["I operated a second account for some time because I was curious to find out whether low-reputation users are really treated much differently than high-reputation users..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101988/165773)

Answer (score 5):

This is just how the Stack Exchange network works. We don't really have a choice in this matter at Workplace.

One thing to be aware of too is that answers posted first often end up voted higher. It is [well known](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/193412) to be an issue with Stack Exchange.

Oftentimes, the more active users have higher rep and are able to post answers first.

Another possibility is high rep users normally have a lot more experience in knowing a site audience. Each site is slightly different in terms of "what gives upvotes" and the more answers you post you start to know what sorts of things people on the site vote for, etc.